# Comprehensive Silverlight rendering resource?

Tags: silverlight, rendering, hittest

Is there any reference available that gives a comprehensive look at how Silverlight renders the controls in an application? The kinds of things I need to know:

What is the bounding rectangle of control X?
Is point P inside control X?
Is control X visible to the user?
How could I manually replicate Silverlight's hit testing?

Rendering and hit testing behavior seem to be governed by large numbers of properties both on a control X and on all of its containers up to the visual tree root. Is there any comprehensive reference to help me figure out how all of this works?

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy) is a great tool that you can use to see all that is going on in the XAML. I've recently read parts of [Silverlight in Action](http://www.manning.com/pbrown/) which has some good in depth information, but I don't know if it answers all your questions.